# DeviceIoControlCE for I2C

Tags: c#, windows-ce, deviceiocontrol

I have been banging my head against a problem for days now. I would like your help.

I am trying to interface to I2C from a board running Windows CE7. The board is a Boundary Devices Nitrogen6X.

I am trying to code this in C#.

After a lot of googling and trial and error I can now do almost everything with the I2C (by that I mean I wrapped most commands in methods that work). Of course, the one thing that I cannot do yet is Reading/Writing. I have been trying a few different implementations, porting C and C++ code that supposedly worked. To no avail. Currently I am putting more effort in the two implementations I will copy here.

Neither of these implementations work for me. Both enter the error management portion, and both report error number 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER).

Does anyone have experience on these kind of issues? could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Edit 1: I should probably mention that I am trying to "see" some signals on the SDA and SCL pins of I2C3: of the board by simply plugging an oscilloscope to them. There is no actual device connected on the I2C bus. I would expect this to give me some sort of error after the first byte (addres+Read/Write) has been sent, because no acknowledge bit would be received. However, I see that error 87 in my code, and no change on the signals as seen from the scope (both remain high on idle).

(Code snippets follow)

The first one uses pointers and stuff, and is probably closer to C++ code:

```
StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    unsafe public struct UNSAFE_I2C_PACKET
    {
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte byAddr; //I2C slave device address
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte byRw; //Read = I2C_Read or Write = I2C_Write
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
        public byte* pbyBuf; //Message Buffer
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public Int16 wLen; //Message Buffer Length
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
        public int* lpiResult; //Contain the result of last operation
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    unsafe public struct UNSAFE_I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK
    {
        //public I2C_PACKET pI2CPackets;
        public UNSAFE_I2C_PACKET* pI2CPackets;
        public Int32 iNumPackets;
    }
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "DeviceIoControl", SetLastError = true)]
    unsafe internal static extern int DeviceIoControlCE(
        IntPtr hDevice, //file handle to driver
        uint dwIoControlCode, //a correct call to CTL_CODE
        [In, Out]byte* lpInBuffer,
        uint nInBufferSize,
        byte* lpOutBuffer,
        uint nOutBufferSize,
        uint* lpBytesReturned,
        int* lpOverlapped);
    unsafe public void ReadI2C(byte* pBuf, int count)
    {
        int ret;
        int iResult;
        UNSAFE_I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK I2CXferBlock = new UNSAFE_I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK();
        UNSAFE_I2C_PACKET i2cPckt = new UNSAFE_I2C_PACKET();

        //fixed (byte* p = pBuf)
        {
            i2cPckt.pbyBuf = pBuf;// p;
            i2cPckt.wLen = (Int16)count;
            i2cPckt.byRw = I2C_READ;
            i2cPckt.byAddr = BASE;
            i2cPckt.lpiResult = &iResult;

            I2CXferBlock.iNumPackets = 1;
            //fixed (I2C_PACKET* pck = &i2cPckt)
            {
                I2CXferBlock.pI2CPackets = &i2cPckt; // pck;
                //fixed (I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK* tBlock = &I2CXferBlock)
                {
                    if (DeviceIoControlCE(_i2cFile,
                                    I2C_IOCTL_TRANSFER,
                                    (byte*)&I2CXferBlock,//tBlock,
                                    (uint)sizeof(UNSAFE_I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK),//Marshal.SizeOf(I2CXferBlock),
                                    null,
                                    0,
                                    null,
                                    null) == 0)
                    {
                        int error = GetLastError();
                        diag("Errore nella TRANSFER");
                        diag(error.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The second option I am working on marshals stuff around between managed and unmanaged:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct I2C_PACKET
    //public class I2C_PACKET
    {
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public Byte byAddr; //I2C slave device address
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public Byte byRw; //Read = I2C_Read or Write = I2C_Write
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
        public IntPtr pbyBuf; //Message Buffer
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public Int16 wLen; //Message Buffer Length
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
        public IntPtr lpiResult; //Contain the result of last operation
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK
    {
        //public I2C_PACKET pI2CPackets;
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
        public IntPtr pI2CPackets;
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public Int32 iNumPackets;
    }
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "DeviceIoControl", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int DeviceIoControlCE(
        IntPtr hDevice, //file handle to driver
        uint dwIoControlCode, //a correct call to CTL_CODE
        [In] IntPtr lpInBuffer,
        uint nInBufferSize,
        [Out] IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
        uint nOutBufferSize,
        out uint lpBytesReturned,
        IntPtr lpOverlapped);
unsafe public void ReadI2C(byte[] buffer)
    {
        int count = buffer.Length;
        I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK I2CXFerBlock = new I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK();
        I2C_PACKET I2CPckt = new I2C_PACKET();

        I2CPckt.byAddr = BASE;
        I2CPckt.byRw = I2C_READ;
        I2CPckt.wLen = (Int16)count;
        I2CPckt.lpiResult = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
        I2CPckt.pbyBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(count);
        //GCHandle packet = GCHandle.Alloc(I2CPckt, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        I2CXFerBlock.iNumPackets = 1;
        I2CXFerBlock.pI2CPackets = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(I2CPckt)); //(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(I2C_PACKET)));//  //(sizeof(I2C_PACKET));// 
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(I2CPckt, I2CXFerBlock.pI2CPackets, false);
        //I2CXFerBlock.pI2CPackets = packet.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        //GCHandle xferBlock = GCHandle.Alloc(I2CXFerBlock, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr xfer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(I2CXFerBlock)); //(sizeof(I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK)); //
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(I2CXFerBlock, xfer, false);
        //IntPtr xfer = xferBlock.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        uint size = (uint)sizeof(I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK);//Marshal.SizeOf(I2CXFerBlock);
        uint getCnt = 0;
        if ((DeviceIoControlCE(_i2cFile,
            I2C_IOCTL_TRANSFER, 
            xfer, 
            size, 
            xfer, //IntPtr.Zero, 
            size, //0, 
            out getCnt, 
            IntPtr.Zero)) == 0)
        {
            int error = GetLastError();
            diag("Errore nella TRANSFER.");
            diag(error.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            //success
            I2CXFerBlock = (I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK)Marshal.PtrToStructure(xfer, typeof(I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK));
            I2CPckt = (I2C_PACKET)Marshal.PtrToStructure(I2CXFerBlock.pI2CPackets, typeof(I2C_PACKET));
            Marshal.Copy(I2CPckt.pbyBuf, buffer, 0, count);
            diag("Success in TRANSFER: " + buffer[0].ToString());
        }
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(I2CPckt.pbyBuf);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(I2CXFerBlock.pI2CPackets);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(xfer);
        //packet.Free();
        //xferBlock.Free();
    }
```

Edit 2: The (supposedly) working code I have (which I am unable to run) comes from drivers I have been given, which might be partially proprietary (hence I cannot share). However I found online the header for an I2C bus, that contains the following definition:

```
#define I2C_MACRO_TRANSFER(hDev, pI2CTransferBlock) \
(DeviceIoControl(hDev, I2C_IOCTL_TRANSFER, (PBYTE) pI2CTransferBlock, sizeof(I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL))
```

I initially tried giving "null" to parameters as it's done here, but I still got the same error code.

Edit 3: From the same driver, the struct definitions:

```
// I2C Packet
typedef struct
{
    BYTE byAddr;       // I2C slave device address for this I2C operation
    BYTE byRW;         // Read = I2C_READ or Write = I2C_WRITE
    PBYTE pbyBuf;      // Message Buffer
    WORD wLen;         // Message Buffer Length
    LPINT lpiResult;   // Contains the result of last operation
} I2C_PACKET, *PI2C_PACKET;

// I2C Transfer Block
typedef struct
{
    I2C_PACKET *pI2CPackets;
    INT32 iNumPackets;
} I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK, *PI2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK;
```

Edit 4: I tried implementing version passing a `ref` to my structures, as @ctacke suggested in his comment. I still get the same error, so I guess I must have done womthing different from the way he thought it. Here is the snippet:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct REF_I2C_PACKET //public class REF_I2C_PACKET //
    {
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public Byte byAddr; //I2C slave device address
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public Byte byRw; //Read = I2C_Read or Write = I2C_Write
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
        public IntPtr pbyBuf; //Message Buffer
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public Int16 wLen; //Message Buffer Length
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
        public IntPtr lpiResult; //Contain the result of last operation
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct REF_I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK //public class REF_I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK //
    {
        //public I2C_PACKET pI2CPackets;
        public IntPtr pI2CPackets;
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public Int32 iNumPackets;
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 2)]
        //public REF_I2C_PACKET[] pI2CPackets;
    }
    [DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "DeviceIoControl", SetLastError = true)]
    unsafe internal static extern int DeviceIoControlCE(
        IntPtr hDevice, //file handle to driver
        uint dwIoControlCode, //a correct call to CTL_CODE
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)]
        //[In] object lpInBuffer, //
        ref REF_I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK lpInBuffer,
        uint nInBufferSize,
        byte* lpOutBuffer, //ref REF_I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK lpOutBuffer,
        uint nOutBufferSize,
        out uint lpBytesReturned, //uint* lpBytesReturned,
        int* lpOverlapped);
    unsafe public void RefReadI2C(byte[] buffer)
    {
        int count = buffer.Length;
        REF_I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK I2CXFerBlock = new REF_I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK();
        REF_I2C_PACKET[] I2CPckt = new REF_I2C_PACKET[2];
        I2CPckt[0] = new REF_I2C_PACKET();
        I2CPckt[1] = new REF_I2C_PACKET();

        I2CPckt[0].byAddr = BASE;
        I2CPckt[0].byRw = I2C_READ;
        I2CPckt[0].wLen = (Int16)count;
        I2CPckt[0].lpiResult = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
        I2CPckt[0].pbyBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(count);
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, I2CPckt[0].pbyBuf, count);

        I2CPckt[1].byAddr = BASE;
        I2CPckt[1].byRw = I2C_READ;
        I2CPckt[1].wLen = (Int16)count;
        I2CPckt[1].lpiResult = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
        I2CPckt[1].pbyBuf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(count);
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, I2CPckt[0].pbyBuf, count);

        I2CXFerBlock.iNumPackets = 2;
        I2CXFerBlock.pI2CPackets = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(I2CPckt[0])*I2CPckt.Length);

        uint size = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(I2CXFerBlock); //sizeof(REF_I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK);//Marshal.SizeOf(I2CXFerBlock);
        //size += (uint)(Marshal.SizeOf(I2CPckt[0]) * I2CPckt.Length);
        uint getCnt = 0;
        if ((DeviceIoControlCE(_i2cFile,
            I2C_IOCTL_TRANSFER,
            ref I2CXFerBlock,
            size,
            null, //IntPtr.Zero, 
            0, //0, 
            out getCnt,
            null)) == 0)
        {
            int error = GetLastError();
            diag("Errore nella TRANSFER.");
            diag(error.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            //success

            I2CPckt = (REF_I2C_PACKET[])Marshal.PtrToStructure(I2CXFerBlock.pI2CPackets, typeof(REF_I2C_PACKET[]));
            Marshal.Copy(I2CPckt[0].pbyBuf, buffer, 0, count);
            diag("Success in TRANSFER: " + buffer[0].ToString());
        }
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(I2CPckt[0].pbyBuf);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(I2CPckt[0].lpiResult);
    }
```

Edit 5:
I found online (http://em-works.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/WINCE600/PLATFORM/COMMON/SRC/SOC/COMMON_FSL_V2_PDK1_9/I2C/PDK/i2c_io.cpp) The following code:

```
BOOL I2C_IOControl(DWORD hOpenContext, DWORD dwCode, PBYTE pBufIn, 
               DWORD dwLenIn, PBYTE pBufOut, DWORD dwLenOut,
               PDWORD pdwActualOut)
{
    /*stuff*/
    case I2C_IOCTL_TRANSFER:
        {
#define MARSHAL 1
#if MARSHAL
            DuplicatedBuffer_t Marshalled_pInBuf(pBufIn, dwLenIn, ARG_I_PTR);
            pBufIn = reinterpret_cast<PBYTE>( Marshalled_pInBuf.ptr() );
            if( (dwLenIn > 0) && (NULL == pBufIn) )
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
#endif
            I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK *pXferBlock = (I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK *) pBufIn;
            if (pXferBlock->iNumPackets<=0) 
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

#if MARSHAL
            MarshalledBuffer_t Marshalled_pPackets(pXferBlock->pI2CPackets, 
                                                   pXferBlock->iNumPackets*sizeof(I2C_PACKET), 
                                                   ARG_I_PTR);

            I2C_PACKET *pPackets = reinterpret_cast<I2C_PACKET *>(Marshalled_pPackets.ptr());
            if( (NULL == pPackets) )
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
#else
            I2C_PACKET *pPackets = pXferBlock->pI2CPackets;
#endif

#if MARSHAL
           struct Marshalled_I2C_PACKET
            {
                MarshalledBuffer_t *pbyBuf;
                MarshalledBuffer_t *lpiResult;
            } *Marshalled_of_pPackets;

            Marshalled_of_pPackets = new Marshalled_I2C_PACKET[pXferBlock->iNumPackets];
            if (Marshalled_of_pPackets==0)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

            MarshalledBuffer_t *pMarshalled_ptr;
            int i;

           // Map pointers for each packet in the array
            for (i = 0; i < pXferBlock->iNumPackets; i++)
            {
                switch( pPackets[i].byRW & I2C_METHOD_MASK )
                {
                case I2C_RW_WRITE:
                    pMarshalled_ptr = new MarshalledBuffer_t(
                                           pPackets[i].pbyBuf,
                                           pPackets[i].wLen,
                                           ARG_I_PTR,
                                           FALSE, FALSE);
                    if (pMarshalled_ptr ==0)
                    {
                        bRet = FALSE;
                        goto cleanupPass1;
                    }
                    if (pMarshalled_ptr->ptr()==0)
                    {
                        bRet = FALSE;
                        delete pMarshalled_ptr;
                        goto cleanupPass1;
                    }
                    break;

                case I2C_RW_READ:
                    pMarshalled_ptr = new MarshalledBuffer_t(
                                           pPackets[i].pbyBuf,
                                           pPackets[i].wLen,
                                           ARG_O_PTR, FALSE, FALSE);
                    if (pMarshalled_ptr ==0)
                    {
                        bRet = FALSE;
                        goto cleanupPass1;
                    }
                    if (pMarshalled_ptr->ptr()==0)
                    {
                        bRet = FALSE;
                        delete pMarshalled_ptr;
                        goto cleanupPass1;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    {
                        bRet = FALSE;
                        goto cleanupPass1;
                    }
                }

                pPackets[i].pbyBuf = reinterpret_cast<PBYTE>(pMarshalled_ptr->ptr());
                Marshalled_of_pPackets[i].pbyBuf = pMarshalled_ptr;
            }

            for (i = 0; i < pXferBlock->iNumPackets; i++)
            {
                pMarshalled_ptr = new MarshalledBuffer_t(
                                 pPackets[i].lpiResult, sizeof(INT), 
                                 ARG_O_PDW, FALSE, FALSE);

                if (pMarshalled_ptr ==0)
                {
                    bRet = FALSE;
                    goto cleanupPass2;
                }
                if (pMarshalled_ptr->ptr()==0)
                {
                    bRet = FALSE;
                    delete pMarshalled_ptr;
                    goto cleanupPass2;
                }
                pPackets[i].lpiResult = reinterpret_cast<LPINT>(pMarshalled_ptr->ptr());
                Marshalled_of_pPackets[i].lpiResult = pMarshalled_ptr;
            }
#endif

            bRet = pI2C->ProcessPackets(pPackets, pXferBlock->iNumPackets);

#if MARSHAL
            DEBUGMSG (ZONE_IOCTL|ZONE_FUNCTION, (TEXT("I2C_IOControl:I2C_IOCTL_TRANSFER -\r\n")));

            i = pXferBlock->iNumPackets;
cleanupPass2:
            for (--i; i>=0; --i)
            {
                delete Marshalled_of_pPackets[i].lpiResult;
            }

            i = pXferBlock->iNumPackets;
cleanupPass1:
            for (--i; i>=0; --i)
            {
                delete Marshalled_of_pPackets[i].pbyBuf;
            }

            delete[] Marshalled_of_pPackets;

#endif
            break;
        }
/*stuff*/
}
```

I cannot claim to understand 100% of it, but from the Windows naming conventions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378932(v=vs.85).aspx) it would appear that the size parameter I should send is the total number of bytes of my transfer, including everything. I have tried to figure that number out myself, but I have so far not been able to. Alternatively, I guess it would be possible to try and do something to the structures I have to turn them into a byte array. Only I guess that it would need to have a specific order of the bytes in it for the system to understand it.
Can anyone pitch in on that?

Comment: Do you have a working C example? If you do, look at the values of the "size" parameters. Make sure those values in your C# code match their values in the working C example. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268889/pinvoke-deviceiocontrol-parameters

Comment: The error indicates you're sending in something wrong, so it's not getting to the wire at all, the driver is rejecting the call. We need to see the C definitions you're trying to replicate. I also suspect you have way too much marshaling going on here. You could define the DeviceIoControl to take a `ref` to your struct and likely eliminate the StructureToPointer.

Comment: @PaulH I added the code I could. Looks like the size that the DeviceIOControl expects is the size of the struct, which in my opinion would be 8 (pointer+int + padding). I also tried adding the size of the Packet, or the array of packets. with no success.

Comment: I'd agree with Paul.  Do you have a working example in C?  Is the driver expecting a non-null output or result buffer?  What you're seeing is an error from the driver, so the solution is going to be specific to this driver.  You have to know it's expectations for all parameters and a working example in C is the best way to start.

Comment: I just googled on [I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK](https://www.google.com/search?q="I2C_TRANSFER_BLOCK") and found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487212/cannot-p-invoke-c-method-from-c-sharp-due-to-marshalling-issues) by @David Heffernan. Have you tried this?

Comment: @PaulH That is the first thing I tried, before getting myself into using DeviceIoControl. However on my platform the PInvoke to i2csdk.dll fails. Even though that dll is in the same folder as coredll.dll, which I am using. And it's an error related to not finding a specific method or entry point (I already went through the exercise of checking that)

Comment: copy the i2csdk.dll to your PC and run `dumpbin /exports i2csdk.dll` to find out what functions are exported from it. But, even if this doesn't work, take a look at how he defines the I2C structures in that question and how he marshalls them. The same techniques should apply to DeviceIoControl.

Comment: @PaulH the errors I get from calling the wrong function in an "accessible" dll is different from the error I get from trying to call anything from a dll which for some reason I have no access to. In the case of i2csdk.dll, I am in the second category. I have been again through that post, and I think I tried all they proposed. Including going through the comment and trying an implementation with GCHandle.Alloc() rather than straight up Marshal.AllocHGlobal(). I saw the same error 87 from that DeviceIoControlCE.